# Updating Rails App with Phusion Passenger and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, server, passenger, phusion

I have a Rails app served via Phusion Passenger and Nginx. I made some changes to both the server and the client side code, recompiled the production assets with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, and attempted to restart both nginx and phusion with the following:

```
# stop then restart nginx
sudo kill $(cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid)
sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx

# restart passenger
passenger-config restart-app
```

However, when I clear my browser cache and rerequest my host address, I see phusion and nginx are still serving the old JavaScript assets, rather than the JS assets I just compiled.

How can I stop then restart the rails server and serve the updated server and client side code? Any help others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how does your production.rb file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my server had two versions of nginx installed. I needed to restart the version of nginx hosting my app with:

`sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx restart`